# Chart.js - Datalabels not showing using formatter

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am trying to use the datalabels' plugin from Chartjs but the labels don't display on the graph at all! I am using >= 2.7.0 (actually 2.9.0) version of Chart.js.

This is my code :

```
var ctx = this.pieChartRef.nativeElement;
    this.pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
        labels: Object.keys(pieData),
        datasets: [
          {
            data: Object.values(pieData),
            backgroundColor: random,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          position: 'bottom',
          display: true,
        },
        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            color: '#fff',
            display: true,
            formatter: function (value, ctx) {
              let sum = 0;
              let dataArr: number[] = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0]
                .data as number[];
              dataArr.map((data) => {
                sum += data;
              });
              return ((value * 100) / sum).toFixed(2) + '%';
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

No datalabel shows up, even if I replace the formatter code by a simple `return value + '%';`... Could you please help me, I am stuck !

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this issue **not** related to versions (2.7 VS 2.9 and so on).
In general, please add a demo.

I guess you want this data [5,5] to display as `50%` `50%` and [3,3,3] ad 33% / 33% / 33%.

**Your issue related to something with the calculations.**

The `sum` looks "**buggy**" (console.log the value). 
The callback runs **more** than one time (One time for each label) - and you put inside `loop` throw array and declare this array again and again.

```
let dataArr: number[] = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data as number[];
dataArr.map((data) => {
  sum += data;
});
```

**This example works fine (Without nested loop):**

```js
var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      data: [5, 10],
      backgroundColor: ["red", "blue"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      display: true,
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        display: true, 
        formatter: function (value, ctx) {
          return ((value * 100) / total(ctx)).toFixed(2) + '%';
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

function total(chart){
  let data = chart.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
  const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
  var total = data.reduce(reducer);
  return total;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
```

### DRY

The code above is also a little **repeatable** - if you declare the data outside of chart.js object you could calculate the `data total` only one time.

```js
var data = [4, 9, 5, 2];
/* get total */
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
var total = data.reduce(reducer);

var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: ["red", "blue", "green", "violet"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      display: true,
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: '#fff',
        display: true, 
        formatter: function (value, ctx) {
          return ((value * 100) / total).toFixed(2) + '%'; 
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="450"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
```

More dry/modular? (For changeable data) Put total data inside function and so on.